# how to store Strings from TextFormField to another page

Tags: flutter, api, url, flutter-textformfield

I have three text form fields on the sign-in page
There are two of them for username and password that work well, I have no problem with them
But the first one is for entering the domain (it is programmed so that each client has its own domain), which is my problem.
I want that when the user enters his domain, the URL of the program, which is in the IP page, is changed and the sign-in page is called only once, without the need to call other pages.

**thsis is signIn page code:**
I suggest that you pay attention to _signIn and ElevatedButton.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mis_project/api/my_api.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:mis_project/conts/myString.dart';
import '../auth/auth_page.dart';
import '../conts/colors.dart';
import '../conts/mSize.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
const SignIn({Key key}) : super(key: key);
@override
_SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
String postDomain;
bool isLoading = false;
PageController _pageController;
List<TextEditingController> tecList;



@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _pageController = PageController();
 tecList = List.generate(3, (index) {
   return TextEditingController();
 });

 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   _showModalBottomSheet(context);
 });
}

_signIn() async {
 print('Sign is is called');
 var data = {
   'email': tecList[1].text,
   'password': tecList[2].text,
 };
 var jsonResponse = null;
 SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 var response = await CallApi().postData(data, 'login');
 jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
 if (jsonResponse != null) {
   setState(() {});
   localStorage.setString('token', jsonResponse['token']);
   Navigator.push(
       context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AuthPage()));
 } else {
   setState(() {});
 }
}

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
void dispose() {
 for (var tec in tecList) {
   tec.dispose();
 }
 super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   backgroundColor: background_page,
   body: isLoading
       ? Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         )
       : Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             image: DecorationImage(
                 image: AssetImage('assets/image/background.jpg'),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover),
           ),
         ),
 );
}

void _showModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
   elevation: 30,
   isScrollControlled: true,
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
       topRight: Radius.circular(30),
     ),
   ),
   context: context,
   builder: (BuildContext context) {
     return SizedBox(
       height: mDeviceSize(context).height * 0.71,
       width: mDeviceSize(context).width,
       child: PageView.builder(
         controller: _pageController,
         itemCount: 3,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
             children: [
               Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                     top: 40, left: 25, right: 25, bottom: 15),
                 child: Form(
                   key: _formKey,
                   child: Column(
                     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                     children: [
                       TextFormField(
                         textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                         textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                         style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                         cursorColor: view_all_color_HP,
                         controller: tecList[index],
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

                         decoration: InputDecoration(
                           focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                             borderSide: BorderSide(
                               color: view_all_color_HP,
                             ),
                           ),
                           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                               vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10),
                           labelText: signing_input_label[index],
                           labelStyle: TextStyle(color: view_all_color_HP),
                           floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                           alignLabelWithHint: true,
                           hintStyle: TextStyle(
                               color: view_all_color_HP,
                               fontSize: 15,
                               fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                         ),

                         autofocus: true,
                         validator: (value) {
                           if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                             return 'Please enter some text';
                           }
                           return null;
                         },
                       ),
                       SizedBox(
                         height: 10,
                       ),
                       ElevatedButton(
                         onPressed: ()  {
                           int nextPage = index + 1;
                           if (nextPage < 3) {
                             _pageController.animateToPage(nextPage,
                                 duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                 curve: Curves.ease);
                           }
                           if (index == 0) {
                             postDomain = tecList[0].text;
                             print('domain post is : $postDomain');
                             print('domain value is: ${tecList[0].text}');
                           }
                           if (index == 1) {
                             print('email value is: ${tecList[1].text}');
                           }

                           if (index == 2) {
                             print('pass: ${tecList[2].text}');

                               _signIn();


                           }
                         },
                         child: Text(signing_button_label[index]),
                         style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                           elevation: 0,
                           primary: view_all_color_HP,
                           fixedSize:
                               Size(mDeviceSize(context).width * 0.3, 5),
                           minimumSize: Size(0, 45),
                         ),
                       ),
                       SizedBox(
                         height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           );
         },
       ),
     );
   },
 );
}

}
```

**and this is my APi page**

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CallApi{

  final String _urlF = 'https://';
  final String _urlE = '.lajwardsoftwares.com/api/v1/';

  postData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _urlF + _urlE + apiUrl + await _getToken();
    print('full url is: $fullUrl');
    return await http.post(
        Uri.parse(fullUrl),
        body: jsonEncode(data),
        headers: _setHeaders()
    );
  }
  getData(apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _urlF + apiUrl + await _getToken();
    return await http.get(
        Uri.parse(fullUrl),
        headers: _setHeaders()
    );
  }


  _setHeaders() => {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
  };

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = localStorage.getString('token');
    return '?token=$token';
    // print("saied: getToken ${localStorage.getString('token')}"),};


  }


}
```

i want this `.lajwardsoftwares.com` to stored from TextFromField

thanks

Comment: lemme me know if another description is needed

Comment: Use https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences or just pass the value as argument to your next page.

Comment: Why not use a state management to store the values and you can call it anywhere in the app.. i suggest you checkout Getx https://pub.dev/packages/get

Comment: hi @stacktrace2234
I will try the sheredPreferences thanks
I tried passing as argument but it need to pass that argument every where I call it, and it is not what I want.